# Why are these while loops not working? Or is something else the problem?

Tags: c#, loops, while-loop

i have just recently started c# as this language is being used for the course at college.
[The top prize in a lottery is won by matching three numbers between 1 and 30 to three random numbers drawn in the same order.
When a ball is drawn it is put back into the machine before another ball is drawn. There are always 30 balls in the machine before a ball is drawn and a player may choose the same ball more than once.
A draw takes place once a week. Write an algorithm that takes three numbers as inputs, repeatedly draws three random numbers between 1 and 30 until there are three matches and returns the number of weeks it took to win the jackpot.-- This is the program i have to create. Is it any better without the picture. When i execute this code, it runs infinitely and doesn't give me a specific answer.

][1]

using System;

namespace challenges
{
class Program
{
static void Main(string[] args)
{
// Lottery Problem

```
        double num1, num2, num3;
        int week = 0;

        Console.Write("Enter the first number: ");
        num1 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Enter the second number: ");
        num2 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Enter the third number: ");
        num3 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

        Random rnd = new Random();
        int ball1 = rnd.Next(1, 31);
        int ball2 = rnd.Next(1, 31);
        int ball3 = rnd.Next(1, 31);

        do
        {
            week++;

            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("it took " + week + " weeks to win the jackpot");
                break;
            } while (ball1 == num1 && ball2 == num2 && ball3 == num3); 
        } while (ball1 != num1 || ball2 != num2 || ball3 != num3);
```

Comment: I'm afraid that images of code aren't any good. We can't debug them, people with sight problems using screen readers can't access the code, etc.

Comment: Expected output? Actual output? What is the question?

Comment: Also note that "I can't understand why it isn't working for me" isn't really a problem statement: what should your code do? what is actually happening? do you get any errors? if you do, please include the full error message in the question (again as text).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have to pass random selection codes into the loop.I mean "that for line that select random numbers".

Comment: okay so am i supposed to put this code inside the loop                                                                                Random rnd = new Random();
        int ball1 = rnd.Next(1, 31);
        int ball2 = rnd.Next(1, 31);
        int ball3 = rnd.Next(1, 31);

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It now gives me one answer. But it still seems wrong as it is a 5 digit number. Why would it take that long to win the lottery???

Comment: @iqra Probably because your code requires the balls in a specific order to be matched in a specific order. That is to say: if num1=5,num2=30,num3=6 then ball1 must equal 5, ball2 must equal 30, and ball3 must equal 6 to match. If (for example) ball1 equals 30, ball2 equals 5, and ball3 equals 6, then although you have the right balls you don't consider that to be a valid combination.

Comment: Other issue: why are you reading the inputs as `double` when the ball values are `int`? A user could enter 5.3 but that would never be a possible result.

Comment: yes of course. you have to put these codes inside the loop